# DIV in NASM always return 1

Tags: linux, nasm

There are my all code:

```
SYS_EXIT  equ 1
SYS_READ  equ 3
SYS_WRITE equ 4
STDIN     equ 0
STDOUT    equ 1

section .data 

   msg1 db `\xF0\x9F\x98\x8E`, " Enter the A: "
   len1 equ $- msg1 

   msg2 db `\xF0\x9F\x98\x89`, " Than the B: "
   len2 equ $- msg2

   msg3 db `\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB0`, " A > B:   A / B - 1 = "
   len3 equ $- msg3

   msg4 db `\xF0\x9F\x8D\xAA`, " A = B: -25"
   len4 equ $- msg4

   msg5 db `\xF0\x9F\x8D\x95`, " A < B: (B^3 - 5) / A = "
   len5 equ $- msg5


section .bss

   a resb 32
   b resb 32
   x resb 32

section .text
   global _start    ;must be declared for using gcc

_start:             ;tell linker entry point
   mov eax, SYS_WRITE
   mov ebx, STDOUT
   mov ecx, msg1
   mov edx, len1
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_READ
   mov ebx, STDIN
   mov ecx, a
   mov edx, 32
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_WRITE
   mov ebx, STDOUT
   mov ecx, msg2
   mov edx, len2
   int 0x80

   mov eax, SYS_READ
   mov ebx, STDIN
   mov ecx, b
   mov edx, 32
   int 0x80

   ; Comparing
   mov eax, [a]
      sub eax, '0'
   mov ecx, [b]
      sub ecx, '0'

   cmp eax, ecx
   jg Ab          ;A grate than b
   je AB          ;A and B are equal
   jl aB          ;a smoller than B

   Ab:
      cdq
      idiv ecx
      dec eax

      add eax, '0'
      mov [x], eax

      mov eax, SYS_WRITE
      mov ebx, STDOUT
      mov ecx, msg3
      mov edx, len3
      int 0x80

      mov eax, SYS_WRITE
      mov ebx, STDOUT
      mov ecx, x
      mov edx, 32
      int 0x80
      jmp exit    ;go to exit

   AB:
      mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
      mov ebx, STDOUT         
      mov ecx, msg4
      mov edx, len4
      int 0x80
      jmp exit    ;go to exit

   aB:
      mov eax, ecx
      imul ecx
      imul ecx
         mov ebx, '5'
            sub ebx, '0'
      sub eax, ebx

      mov ecx, [a]
         sub ecx, '0'
      idiv ecx

      add eax, '0'
      mov [x], eax

      mov eax, SYS_WRITE
      mov ebx, STDOUT
      mov ecx, msg5
      mov edx, len5
      int 0x80

      mov eax, SYS_WRITE
      mov ebx, STDOUT
      mov ecx, x
      mov edx, 1
      int 0x80

exit:    

   mov eax, SYS_EXIT   
   xor ebx, ebx 
   int 0x80
```

In 'a' and 'b' I put different number between 0 and 9 but this operation always return 1. I checked out EDX and noticed that processor subtracts ECX from EAX only one times. In EAX he write 1, and in EDX - remainder from subtraction EAX and ECX.

When I enter a = 9 and b = 4 : EAX after dividing = 1 and EDX = 5. If I enter a = 6 and b = 2 : EAX = 1, EDX = 4

What happened?

Comment: Where are the declarations of `a` and `b`?

Comment: So what are some example inputs and outputs? And how did you establish that `eax` always gets the value 1 after the division? I don't see any code that prints the value of `eax`.

Comment: Sorry there mast be don't EDX but EAX. But not the problem. It's I just test registers.

Comment: _processor subtracts ECX from EAX_ - where?

Comment: When I call DIV he write in EDX remainder: EAX - ECX, and in EAX he write 1 (he 1 times subtracts ECX from EAX)

Comment: He only 1 time subtract ECX from EAX

Comment: You still haven't provided a verifyable example that reproduces what you describe. Or listed some example inputs and outputs along with information about how you checked the output values.

Comment: When I enter a = 9 and b = 4 : EAX after dividing = 1 and EDX = 5. 
 If I enter a = 6 and b = 2 : EAX = 1, EDX = 4

Comment: I want get entire quotient don't 1! There wrong reminder!

Comment: Unable to reproduce. If I store (the `dword`s) `'9'` and `'4'` at `a` and `b` I get the expected results 2 and 1. The problem is in some part of the code that you're not showing us.

Comment: I hope this help)

Comment: Presumably there's a newline character (0xA) after each of the digits. So you end up dividing `0xA09` by `0xA04`. You could e.g. use `movzx eax, byte [a]` instead (and similarly for `b`).

Comment: Wherever you load those values from memory.

Comment: Thanks)) It work. Write your answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably there's a newline character (`0xA`) after each of the digits. So you end up dividing `0xA09` by `0xA04`. You could e.g. use `movzx eax, byte [a]` instead (and similarly for `b`).